# How to display JPEG image on microcontroller LCD?

Tags: image, arm, microcontroller

I am recently developing some firmware on the STM3210E development board which has an ARM cortex M3 processor. It has been interfaced to a 240x320 LCD. After going through the demo firmware, I realised that images are encoded in 32 bit variables (correct me if I am wrong) stored in array as shown below.

uint32_t STM32Banner[50] = {0x6461EB7A, 0x646443BC, 0x64669BFE, 0x6468F440, 0x646B4C82,
                       0x646DA4C4, 0x646FFD06, 0x64725548, 0x6474AD8A, 0x647705CC,
                       0x64795E0E, 0x647BB650, 0x647E0E92, 0x648066D4, 0x6482BF16,
                       0x64851758, 0x64876F9A, 0x6489C7DC, 0x648C201E, 0x648E7860,
                       0x6490D0A2, 0x649328E4, 0x64958126, 0x6497D968, 0x649A31AA,
                       0x649C89EC, 0x649EE22E, 0x64A13A70, 0x64A392B2, 0x64A5EAF4,
                       0x64A84336, 0x64AA9B78, 0x64ACF3BA, 0x64AF4BFC, 0x64B1A43E,
                       0x64B3FC80, 0x64B654C2, 0x64B8AD04, 0x64BB0546, 0x64BD5D88,
                       0x64BFB5CA, 0x64C20E0C, 0x64C4664E, 0x64C6BE90, 0x64C916D2,
                       0x64CB6F14, 0x64CDC756, 0x64D01F98, 0x64D277DA, 0x64D4D01C}

Could you please explain me how to convert a JPEG/PNG/BMP image to this format (RGB565)  ?

Comment: my bad. They are 32 bit numbers indeed. It was more of an human error. So how do i convert a Jpeg file to this format ?

Comment: We don't know what that format is, so your question is impossible to answer as posed. But it will at least involve [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Sorry for the inadequate information. Well, I thought that someone who have worked on STM might have a clue about it. Nvm, After reading a few data sheets, I realised that these arrays are RGB565 format. So how do I convert a jpg/bmp to RGB565 format (particularly in an array form) ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Write your own set of decoders.
2. Use available free decoders

The first solution is only really viable for BMP (and perhaps GIF), which is quite a simple format compared to PNG and JPEG. Even so, writing a BMP decoder that handles all different versions and specialties of BMP gracefully takes quite a bit of work (I have tried it). Hacking together something that can extract the image data from the most common BMP formats is quite easy though.

The second solution is probably the way to go for the other formats. Most open-source decoders are available under LGPL or similar, so licensing shouldn't really be a problem. For JPEG images use [libJPEG](http://www.ijg.org/), for PNG use [libPNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) and for GIF use [giflib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/giflib/).

Most of the decoders do not support decoding to RGB565 so you will have to write a converter to convert from RGB888 to RGB565.

Answer (score 0):

use a program like GIMP to convert to an uncompressed bmp (what you normally get when you save-as bmp).

A bmp has something like a 54 byte header then it goes into the data.  Each line is pixels either 3 bytes (RGB) or four bytes (RGBX) per pixel.  The width is aligned on a 4 byte boundary so if you have three bytes per and multiply that by the width in pixels if that is not a multiple of four (say 3 bits wide * 3 = 9 as a simple example) then there will be some padding.  You know from opening the file in gimp how wide it is, you probably want to use gimp to adjust the image to match your lcd screen anyway.  The first bytes of data after the header are the pixel in the lower left corner of the image, you might need to flip the image in the y axis, or just start off this way and see what happens.

Knowing the size of your image, (from opening it with gimp), you can do a little math to see if the size of the file matches with what I am saying, if it is dramatically smaller then there is some compression going on and you need to save again and change the settings for the bmp.

Once you have this figured out then write a simple program to extract the pixels from the bmp and save them in the format you desire.  Even better read the code and docs and understand how to program the lcd and you can get from raw pixels to the lcd without having to to through their specific format/code.